# Exiftool Not Printing to File in ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, ubuntu, process, java-8, exiftool

I'm using a `ProcessBuilder` to print the output of `exiftool` to a file. I'm trying to run this command on an .opus file: `exiftool Aero.opus > Aero.txt`. This runs just fine in terminal, but in the processbuilder it appears to have trouble parsing it.

Here is a simple program of it. Note that the directory is set to `/home/sarah` and the `Aero.opus` file exists in that directory.

Note also that the output prints to the console instead of to the file like it's supposed to, and that it says that it can't recognize the > operator.

```
@Test
public void testExifprocess() throws IOException {
    //File Located at /home/sarah/Aero.opus
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("exiftool", "Aero.opus", ">", "Aero.txt").directory(Paths.get("/home/sarah").toFile())
            .inheritIO();
    builder.start();
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Running com.protonmail.sarahszabo.stellaropusconverter.tests.StellarDiskManagerTest
File not found: >
File not found: Aero.txt
======== Aero.opus
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
File Name                       : Aero.opus
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 13 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:06:29 19:19:08-04:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:07:16 23:20:27-04:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:07:16 23:20:27-04:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : OPUS
File Type Extension             : opus
MIME Type                       : audio/ogg
Opus Version                    : 1
Audio Channels                  : 2
Sample Rate                     : 48000
Output Gain                     : 1
Vendor                          : Lavf58.17.100
Title                           : Aero
Artist                          : Daniel Deluxe
Picture Type                    : Front Cover
Picture MIME Type               : image/png
Picture Description             : Daniel Deluxe -- Aero.png
Picture Width                   : 1280
Picture Height                  : 720
Picture Bits Per Pixel          : 0
Picture Indexed Colors          : 0
Picture Length                  : 946992
Picture                         : (Binary data 946992 bytes, use -b     option to extract)
    1 image files read
    2 files could not be read

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Home Folder:
[image: Home Folder]

My OS is Kubuntu 18.04, with Java 8_171.

Comment: Redirection is a feature of the _shell_, so it will work only if you invoke exiftool via `bash` (or whatever shell you use).  Use the redirection features of `ProcessBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it's just passing ">" as an argument to exiftool.  I suggest you use
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.io.File)

```
ProcessBuilder proc= new ProcessBuilder().command("exiftool", "Aero.opus");
proc.redirectErrorStream(true);
proc.redirectOutput(new File("Aero.txt"));
proc.start();
```

Comment: So we can't use the underlying shell > feature? Interesting solution though.

Comment: @SarahSzabo there is no underlying shell in `ProcessBuilder`, hence, no shell feature is available. You can’t use `>` etc for output control and you can’t invoke internal commands or aliases. If you want to use shell features, you’d have to invoke the shell as primary command and provide arguments to tell it to run another command. But there is no sense in letting a shell interpret `>` when you can provide the target output handle in the first place.